# How to configure Static IP's (internal or lan IP) in my ubuntu (VPS)

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualbox, ethernet

First of all greetings to all
i have a problem with ubuntu 
i am running ubuntu server 12.04 LTS with GUI (GNOME)
Well its a VPS

This is my eth0

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8e:a3:65:ba:83:bc
          inet addr:207.xxx.xxx.27  Bcast:207.xxx.xxx.31  Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: fxxx::8cxx:6xxx:fxxx:83bc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:269487 errors:0 dropped:68 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:202111 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:39408403 (39.4 MB)  TX bytes:92849451 (92.8 MB)
```

I have eth0 , vboxnet0 and virbr0 interfaces

Now the problem is my eth0 has external ip address configured 
i have install virtualbox 
now i am not getting internet in bridge interface 
NAT is fine

but when i configure the vbox in NAT host system(ubuntu) couldnt ping the OS inside Vbox

Now is there any way to give a static ip's (LAN like 192.168.1.1) to my HOST (ubuntu) and configure the same in bridge mode inside the vbox

Please do help me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved with the Bridged Adapter and the following configuration:

***/etc/network/interfaces***

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.0.250
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Remember to launch the networking restart command:

***sudo service networking restart***

For the sake of completeness find below my `ifconfig` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **:**:**:**:**:**
          inet addr:192.168.0.11  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: ****::***:****:****:****/** Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5214910 (5.2 MB)  TX bytes:288520 (288.5 KB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **:**:**:**:**:**
          inet addr:192.168.0.250  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4694 (4.6 KB)  TX bytes:4694 (4.6 KB)
```

*Tested with Ubuntu server 13.10 x64 (Guest) and Windows 8.1 (Host)*